# Eclipse compare editor differentiation block border color

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, compare, eclipse-juno

I searched on the web to change the color of differentiation block border in Compare editor of eclipse(Juno). I tried change through the Preferences>appearance>Colors and Fonts, But it doesn't has block border color to change.

[image]

In the above image, showing comparing differences with a white border, I want change it to blue.
Can any one please tell me, How to change differentiation block border color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you looking for.

General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Text Compare > Outgoing change color

FYI, I'm using 'indigo' and 'juno' is not so different I guess.

image link:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6HcX.png

Comment: Yes I wanted this. Perfect.